# How to set Android DialogFragment in screen bottom by xml?

Tags: android, dialog, gravity

i can set the DialogFragment in screen bottom by java ,like this

```
public Dialog onCreateDialog(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        setStyle(STYLE_NO_TITLE, R.style.DialogBottom);
        Dialog dialog = super.onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState);
        Window window = dialog.getWindow();
        if (window != null) {
            window.setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM);
        }
        return dialog;
    }
```

but i want set this by xml,like :

```
<style name="DialogBottom" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Dialog.Alert">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@null</item>
        <item name="android:windowMinWidthMinor">100%</item>
        <item name="android:windowMinWidthMajor">100%</item>
        <!--which attr can set Dialog in screen bottom ???-->
    </style>
```

but i dont know which attr...

Comment: Use BottomSheetDialogFragment for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no way of doing this by XML. `BottomSheetDialog` class was designed for this purpose.

You can take a look at this Medium post on how to use it: https://medium.com/@wise4rmgodadmob/a-simple-example-of-using-bottomsheetdialog-in-android-development-using-kotlin-152be3b29737

Comment: Thinks vvvvvvvver macth. This solves my problem perfectly. I have been busy at work recently, so my reply was late.sorry

Comment: Glad to know it was what you are looking for! If the answer solved your problem, consider selecting it as your accepted answer. Regards!